# Json Array Request with volley not works

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

I have Json value like this

```
{
"events": [2]
0:  {
"no": 1
"id": "2"
"nama": "Meja dengan kaki kuda"
"harga": 700000
"gambar": "poster/Donor_darah.jpg"
"stok": 39
"qty": 3
"status": 0
"total": 2100000
}-
1:  {
"no": 2
"id": "1"
"nama": "Lemari"
"harga": 500000
"gambar": "poster/grand-launching-gerakan-ui-mengajar-51.png"
"stok": 0
"qty": 4
"status": 0
"total": 2000000
}-
-
"total": 4100000
}
```

and then I want to retrieve it in my android app with volley like this

```
JsonArrayRequest arrReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, DATA_GET_NOTIF + page,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        if (response.length() > 0) {
                            try {
                                for (int a = 0; a < response.length(); a++) {
                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(a);
                                    JSONArray event = obj.getJSONArray("events");
                                    Log.d("JsonArray",response.toString());

                                    // Parsing json
                                    for (int i = 0; i < event.length(); i++) {

                                        JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) event.get(i);
                                        Cart news = new Cart();

                                        int total = 0;
                                        no = jb.getInt("no");

                                        news.setId(jb.getString("id"));
                                        news.setJudul(jb.getString("nama"));
                                        news.setHarga(jb.getInt("harga"));
                                        news.setStok(jb.getInt("stok"));
                                        news.setQty(jb.getInt("qty"));
                                        news.setStatus(jb.getInt("status"));
                                        news.setTotal(jb.getInt("total"));


                                        if (jb.getString("gambar") != "") {
                                            news.setImageUrl(jb.getString("gambar"));
                                        }


                                        // adding news to news array
                                        eventList.add(news);

                                        if (no > offSet)
                                            offSet = no;

                                        Log.d(TAG, "offSet " + offSet);


                                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                }
                            }catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        swipe.setRefreshing(false);
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }

        }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("authorization", apikeys);
            return params;
        }};

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(arrReq);
```

why it is not appear in my app. because it works before I add "events" array in my json value. so before I add events array my json value justlike this

```
[2]
0:  {
"no": 1
"id": "17"
"judul": "Compfest 8 Seminar"
"deskripsi": "tes"
"duit": 47
"persen": 47
"sisahari": 47
}-
1:  {
"no": 2
"id": "19"
"judul": "Grand Launching Gerakan UI Mengajar 5"
"deskripsi": "tes"
"duit": 80
"persen": 80
"sisahari": 80
}
```

and my code when it works like this :

```
JsonArrayRequest arrReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, DATA_GET_NOTIF + page,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        if (response.length() > 0) {
                            // Parsing json
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {


                                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Cart news = new Cart();

                                    int total = 0;
                                    no = obj.getInt("no");

                                    news.setId(obj.getString("id"));
                                    news.setJudul(obj.getString("nama"));
                                    news.setHarga(obj.getInt("harga"));
                                    news.setStok(obj.getInt("stok"));
                                    news.setQty(obj.getInt("qty"));
                                    news.setStatus(obj.getInt("status"));
                                    news.setTotal(obj.getInt("total"));


                                    if (obj.getString("gambar") != "") {
                                        news.setImageUrl(obj.getString("gambar"));
                                    }
```

Comment: Since your response begins with a curly brace, it is considered a json object (that happens to contain a jsonarray)... but i think the onresponse () is expecting a pure array which should begin with a square bracket.  Is there any reason you need to have the name of the array included?

Comment: ya I need it, so I can sum one object and put it outside of "events" array. it already solved though. just silly mistake with starting json value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your json format when it work

```
**[2]**
0:  {
"no": 1
"id": "17"
"judul": "Compfest 8 Seminar"
"deskripsi": "tes"
"duit": 47
"persen": 47
"sisahari": 47
}-
```

it starts with array first so you can use jsonarrayrequest

but when you change your json format it starts with Json object not array again

```
**{**
"events": [2]
0:  {
"no": 1
"id": "2"
"nama": "M
```

So you can use jsonobjectrequest instead of jsonarrayrequest or the second option you just change your new json format with array first instead of object

Comment: ahhh I see now. It works now when I start my json value with array and still using JsonArrayRequest. thanks